# How can I use jQuery UJS to submit a form via AJAX after the change event of a select box fires in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

How can I use jQuery UJS to submit a form after the change event of a select box fires in Rails?

My view looks like this:

```
<% for perm in @permissions %>
  <%= form_for [@brand,perm], { :remote => true } do |f| %>
    <tr id="permission_<%= perm.id %>">
      <td><%= perm.configurable.name %></td>
      <td><%= f.select :action, ['none', 'read', 'update', 'manage'] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Pretty straightforward.  My controller is like so:

```
class PermissionsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    respond_to :html, :js

    load_and_authorize_resource :brand
    load_and_authorize_resource :permission, :through => :brand

    def index
    end

    def update
      @permission = Permission.find(params[:id])
      @permission.update_attributes(params[:permission])
    end

end
```

And in my application.js:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
$(function() {
  $("#permission_action").change(function() {
    this.form.submit(); // This needs to be an AJAX call, but how?
  });
})
```

Please note that the form submission fires just fine. But it is doing a regular post rather than an AJAX submission. When I place a submit button on the form and use that, the AJAX submission works fine.  I need to change:

```
this.form.submit();
```

to an AJAX call, but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are already using jQuery that's good. Following code was taken from here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

I strongly advise you get familiar with these screen casts they help a ton (understatement).

```
// public/javascripts/application.js
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_review").submitWithAjax();
})
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo. I actually watched this screencast today, and tried the example. To refer to the form, I used "this.form.submitWithAjax();" since I am trying to refer to the form from the change event of a select box. I kept getting "submitWithAjax is not a function".

Comment: I'm not in a position to try this but can you change the line this.submit(....) in the submitWithAjax definition to this.form.submit(....). Maybe you tried idk. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, there is no combination of this that works for me. It's very, very frustrating.  I finally did get this to work:


     $("#permission_action").change(function() {
  
       $.ajax({  
         type: "PUT",  
         url: this.form.action,  
         data: "permission[action]=" + $("#permission_action").val()  
       });  
       return false;
     });

but it only worked for the VERY FIRST LINE! Every row on the screen has a form with a select box called "permission_action". I wasn't aware that jQuery would only bind to the first element of a particular name by default.

Comment: Well you have an obvious misunderstanding of what ids are used for in html, they should be unique, use class selectors if that's not the case. If you have multiple forms in your document you need to be able to differentiate between them; the "this" key would help you I think but I can't really know for sure what you need. It shouldn't be that hard to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Switch #permission_action for a class selector and use .permission_action.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with me Hugo.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the jquery-ujs sources, i figured that this might be the safest way:

```
// in application.js
jQuery.fn.ajaxSubmit = function() {
    this.trigger('submit.rails');
};
```

it just fires the event as would .submit() but in a ujs flavour, so you would call

```js
$('.my_form').ajaxSubmit();
```